# Access JSON keys properly

Tags: javascript, pug

Stupid I know but I have a problem accessing json keys.

```
results: {
  dogs: [
    {
       _id: "5a50c9775ab35b05a0e0b4cd",
       name: "andy",
       age: 27,
       type: "alley",
       __v: 0
    }
       ],
  cats: [
    {
       _id: "5a4de0a0662db23b398715a7",
       name: "mike",
       age: 40,
       type: "alley",
       __v: 0
    }
        ]
}
```

I render the output with:

```
res.render('pets', {pets: 'pets', json: results});
```

pets.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Pets
    each key in json
    h3=key // not sure how to access results.dog/cat here, shows [object Object] only
        each item in key
            p Name: #{item.name}
            p Age: #{item.age}
            p Type: #{item.type}
            p Id: #{item._id}
```

Is there another way of doing this output, where I can access the actual object variable name (in this case dogs or cats). Or is it just the way I send the json object?

Output:

```
Pets

[object Object]
Name: andy
Age: 27
Type: alley
Id: 5a50c9775ab35b05a0e0b4cd

[object Object]
Name: mike
Age: 40
Type: alley
Id: 5a4de0a0662db23b398715a7
```

So my goal is to replace the [object Object] with cats/dogs

Comment: This is not JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `each` with only one parameter, so your variable `key` corresponds to your object and not your key.

[See the doc](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)

You need to get the index and the value like the following (from the doc) :

```
each val, index in {1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'}
  // index: 1,2,3 ; val: 'one','two','three'
```

Hope it helps,
Best regards

Comment: Thanks. Used each key, i in json and set h3=i and got the expected result.